# What happens when a GridDB container reaches its capacity?

Tags: griddb

I am using GridDB to manage a dataset for my IoT project, and it's been great. However, as the data keeps increasing, I'm concerned about the capacity of my containers and what happens when they reach their limit?

I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/tqlreference/type/#primitive), but didn't find clear information on container capacity or how GridDB handles data overflow.

My question is,
Is there a maximum capacity for containers in GridDB, and if there is, what is it?
What will happen when a container reaches its capacity. Are new records rejected, or is there some sort of overflow mechanism?